# Push array while defining the key

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$daysArray = array(2=>array('#linkhere','linked-day'));
```

I need to push another array into here but define the key.

I have tried:

```
$value= $key.'=>array("#$event","linked-day")';
//$value= 2=>array('/weblog/archive/2004/Jan/02','linked-day')
array_push($daysArray, $value);
```

Comment: You're going to need to rephrase.

Comment: This is ambiguous. What should the array look like after the new element has been added?

Comment: if you're just trying to add another element to the array, then use @Jasper's answer.  if you're trying to treat your array like a stack, then you can't assign the keys with `array_push`, its function signature just doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append another array onto your primary array you can use:

```
$daysArray[$key] = array($event, "linked-day");
```

Doc: http://us.php.net/array_push

From the Docs:

```
Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.
```

Answer (score 0):

you to try:

$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);